# oCanvas Chart onHover show data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onhover, ocanvas

I'm making a line chart in oCanvas, and I need to show the data of a point of the line, when the user hovers that point with his mouse! Is there like a built-in function for it do it itself, or do I have to make it myself? (I didn't find any useful info on the docs section of the website, and that's why I came here, just in case someone has done it before me and knows how to do it!). I have the data I need to display when the user hovers the point, I just can't get find a hover function. After that I need to show something like a tooltip, that's gonna contain the data. Thank you very much for your help, it is really useful to me! Here's the website: http://ocanvas.org/

Answer (score 0):

oCanvas is a general purpose library, so there is no built-in feature for that. To make hover work, you need to listen to events (mouseenter and mouseleave): http://ocanvas.org/docs/Events/Mouse

When you detect mouseenter you will need to show the tooltip object in the correct position. When you later detect mouseleave you will need to hide the tooltip.

Comment: Is there a way to track where the cursor is? In order to have the tooltip, above the cursor!

Comment: Yes, use the mousemove event and access either event.x or canvas.mouse.x.